# How to name an interface which shows the existence of a property?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I want to create an interface which should tell its client that the type has a **realm** property, but I'm struggling on how to name it.

Something like **HasRealm** or **HasRealmProperty**? Are the any conventions on how to name such an interface?

**Edit**

By property I mean `attribute`.

**Edit 2**

Further, the interface has to provide a `setRealm(String realm)` method. So, it's more like `SettableRealm` (sry, I'm not good at naming).

Comment: "By property I mean attribute" - what does that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've encountered similar-goal interfaces having the suffix `Aware`. So, in your case it will be `RealmAware`.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean any ['official' convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) I would say: no there isn't any convention. And as long as you keep consistent in your project, it doesn't matter. Personally I would go by "HasRealm".

Comment: Hm... Just checked it again and it works for me. Alternativly search for "Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language" on the Oracle site or give the overview-link a try: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-135089.html

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't vote for `HasRealm`. You probably don't need an interface just to remember or note, that a class *has a* realm. Interfaces define methods. The interface probably has a method to *get* a realm (from a class), and even in that case, we wouldn't have to care, if that realm *belongs* to the instance or if that class is simply capable of providing a realm.

I'd make it depend on the interface method. Like, if the interface defines a `getRealm()` method, then it could be named `RealmProvider` or `RealmSource`.

Comment: I'm not sure I like `Provider`.  In Java a Provider is normally for when you have a implementation to sit behind an API such as Security Provider or a JMS Provider.  So you would have a *single* Security Provider in your environment.  From the question I'm inferring that lots of classes have Realms so there will be lots of classes implementing the interface which isn't the same as a Provider.

Comment: On the other hand, *...Provider* is used quite often in the eclipse framework, like the [ISelectionProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FISelectionProvider.html).

Comment: Well I still don't like it.  :-)  As there is no standard I guess it's all a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

What about **RealmSupport** or **RealmAware**?